# Array foreach to form display and get the same result

Tags: php, arrays, forms, foreach

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [data1] => Array
        (
            [name] => jhon
            [status] => 1
            [address] => 1
        )

    [data2] => Array
        (
            [name] => mayer
            [status] => 1
            [date] => 0
            [height] => 180
        )

    [data3] => Array
        (
            [name] => kilo
            [status] => 0
            [weight] => 0
            [Age] => 18
        )

)
```

And then show the array in my template like this

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="act" value="do_add">

    foreach ($datas as $data){
     echo $data['name'];
       foreach ($data as $key => $value): ?>
         echo $key.' <input name="$key[]" type="text" value="$value">';
       }
    }

</form>
```

And I put all of that code in my php file. The foreach inside the form submit.

The code was perfectly show me everything, but I have an error result as the submited data.

The submitted data give me an array like this.

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => jhon
            [1] => mayer
            [2] => kilo
        )

    [status] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )

    [address] => Array
        (
            [0] => street
        )

    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019
        )

    [height] => Array
        (
            [0] => 190
        )

    [weight] => Array
        (
            [0] => 80
        )

    [age] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
        )

)
```

The question is, how can I get result as the same as my array. I need my old array to be updated to new value as the submit form clicked. Just like the array format before submit data.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing your HTML code incorrectly, if you want to have indexed values:

```
echo $key.' <input name="$key[]" type="text" value="$value">';
```

This line is parsing to, ex, `name="status[]"` which is not what you want.

Instead, modify the lines to read as:

```
<?php
    foreach ($datas as $k => $data) {
        echo $data['name'];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            echo $key.' <input name="$k[$key]" type="text" value="$value">';
        }
    }
?>
```

Now this parses as `name="data1[status]"`

Comment: Note, you've kept some syntax errors from the OP.  First, the inner `foreach` should be opened with a curly brace, not alternative syntax.  Second, since single-quotes are the container for the `echo` in the inner loop, the PHP variables will not be interpreted as such.  Either swap the single- and double- quotes, or use concatenation for the PHP variables.